Custom Identity overriding my validation rules
I hope someone helps me with this. I've been stuck the whole day.
Basically I created a new IdentityUser and use sub class ApplicationUser inheriting from IdentityUser. My only issue is the validation because I feel like IdentityUser is using its validation rules instead of mine.
Because every time a user input fewer than 6 characters, it always causes a validation error for the FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone and Address. It should be only 2 characters, not 6 characters up
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The field must be at least 2 characters long.")]
    [MaxLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Location should only have 100 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The field must be at least 2 characters long.")]
    [MaxLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Location should only have 100 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The field must be at least 2 characters long.")]
    [MaxLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Location should only have 100 characters.")]
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The field must be at least 2 characters long.")]
    [MaxLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Location should only have 100 characters.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public Division Division { get; set; }
    
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

The identity user will not affect outside the default ones, please provide the details codes with the view codes to let us reproduce the issue.
